# BigQuery: How to run analytical function query on a partition table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with several versions of the same data. Each version can be identified by a timestamp field.

This is the query I came up with to fetch only the latest version of my data, using a window function:

```
WITH tbl AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    first_value(`timestamp`) OVER (PARTITION BY concatenate ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC) AS latest
  FROM
    dataset.table as tbl
)

SELECT
  *  
FROM tbl
WHERE
  `timestamp` = latest;
```

Concatenate is a combination of fields that represents the uniqueness of my rows.

That works, however, to optimize this, I created a partitioned table as follows to reduce the amount of data processed on my query due to many versions of the data:

```
CREATE TABLE
  `dataset.partitioned_table`
PARTITION BY
  DATE(`timestamp`)
  CLUSTER BY concatenate AS
SELECT * FROM `dataset.table`;
```

However, when I run the query on the new partitioned data, BigQuery processes the exact amount of data as with the non-partitioned one, being that it should process about a third (I'm testing with 3 versions of the data).

My feeling is that the window function is going over the whole data and there might be a better way to accomplish this when using a partitioned table, however, I couldn't yet find how to do this.

Also tried creating a table partitiones by a fake date but clustered by timestamp and concatenate fields, but got same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is reading the whole table every time because of the way it is written.

Check the CTE (the `WITH` clause), it is not constrained by any `WHERE` clause to reduce the amount of data you read.

If you wanted to read only the latest partition of your table you would have to do something like:

```
WITH tbl AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    first_value(`timestamp`) OVER (PARTITION BY concatenate ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC) AS latest
  FROM
    dataset.table as tbl

  #### this is the super important bit to reduce your reads ####
  WHERE DATE(timestamp) >= DATE('whatever_you_think_your_last_few_partitions_should_be')

)

SELECT
  *  
FROM tbl
WHERE
  `timestamp` = latest;
```

Basically, you need to filter with a `WHERE` early on in your query to reduce the amount of data you process.

Keep in mind I added `whatever_you_think_your_last_few_partitions_should_be` as this really depends on if you want to scan the last X number of partitions for duplicates, or a date range of 1 week, or maybe just literally the last day. Depends on your solution.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the key part of it. It works 100% now.